# Display sharepoint list item in unorderlist list using spfx

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I am trying to insert sharepoint list items in UL. right now each item is added in separate UL. please help how to iterate and add all sharepoint list item in one UL.

```
public componentDidMount(){ 
      if(this.props.Dropdownprop != undefined){
      }
      alert("second" + this.props.Dropdownprop);
        var reactHandler = this; 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "https://sharepointprod.sharepoint.com/teams/SharepointPOC/_api/lists(guid'"+this.props.Dropdownprop+"')/items", 
            type: "GET", 
            headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'}, 
            success: function(resultData) {          
              reactHandler.setState({ 
                items: resultData.d.results,
              }); 
            }, 
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            } 
        }); 
      }
      public render(): React.ReactElement<IScrollTickerWebPartProps> {
        return ( 
           <div>
                 {this.state.items.map(function(item,key){     
                   return (<div className={styles.marquee} key={key}> 
                   <span>
                       <div>
                       <ul className={styles.jsnews}>
                       <li>{item.Title}</li>
                       </ul>
                       </div> 
                       </span>
                     </div>); 
                 })}                    
             </div> 
       ); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review this part of your code in your `render` method:

```
                 {this.state.items.map(function(item,key){     
                   return (<div className={styles.marquee} key={key}> 
                   <span>
                       <div>
                       <ul className={styles.jsnews}>
                       <li>{item.Title}</li>
                       </ul>
                       </div> 
                       </span>
                     </div>); 
                 })}
```

You are using `map` to turn each `this.state.items` into a `div className={styles.marquee}`. Since each of these `div`s has a `ul` in it, you are actually creating one `ul` for **each** of the items in `this.state.items`.

Instead, you should turn each of the `this.state.items` into a `li`, and put all of it into **one** `ul`. You can still do this with `map`, but it will have to be moved deeper into the HTML structure. See this example:

```
<ul className={styles.jsnews}>
    {this.state.items.map(function(item,key){
        return (<li>{item.Title}</li>);
    }}
</ul>
```

Comment: So I'm struggling with a click event on the <li> tag.  If i want to update the UX based on the id of the listitem that is clicked, how do I add a onclick event to the return statement, and pass the id of the item?

Comment: Untested, but I usually do something like this: `return (<li onClick={doSomething.bind(this, item.id)}>...</li>);`. And the function looks like: `var doSomething = function(itemId, ...otherArgs) { /* do whatever */ }`.

The [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) allows you to pass through any additional arguments - for example, values that would be available in the scope of the React code, but not in the scope of the onClick call.

Comment: Here's [a very basic Pen](https://codepen.io/lirichard2013/pen/BbEMjM) demonstrating that use of `bind`.